# The name does not exist in the current context after SetUp in unity testing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, testing, nunit

I'm trying to make unit tests in unity, as I have repeated code, I tried to use SetUp like this

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
  PlayerState playerState = (PlayerState)ScriptableObject.CreateInstance("PlayerState");
}

[Test]
public void IsPlayerWinnerTest()
{
  playerState.LastAnswerTime = 6f;
  playerState.IsLastAnswerCorrect = true;
}
```

So for example, If I have something like this, I get: The name 'playerState' does not exist in the current context. Any idea? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you declare `PlayerState playerState` as **local** variable inside a method ... move it to the class as a **field** and you should be fine

```
public class YOURCLASS
{
    // Now it is a class field so every method nows it
    PlayerState playerState

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        playerState = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<PlayerState>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void IsPlayerWinnerTest()
    {
        playerState.LastAnswerTime = 6f;
        playerState.IsLastAnswerCorrect = true;
    }
}
```